# What is the <div> and <span> elements for?

Tags: html

I am learning how to code HTML from websites and other people. This one site mentioned the `<div>` and `<span>` element but didn't really give a good definition of them. Can someone tell me exactly what they are for and how to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divs are sort like the blocked pieces of a website

- EXAMPLES : Header, body, footer, login-box

Spans are typically for inline elements such as text

- EXAMPLES : Paragraphs, titles

Both pretty much do the same thing (You will use the div more often).

Comment: How are they used though?

Comment: `<span>Hello World</span>` and `<div>Block codes</div>` You can style these elements by giving them an id : EXAMPLE : `<div id="theID"></div>` Now to style them go to the css file and (hopefully you know css) do this div#theID { properties; }

Answer (score -1):

Both mean nothing, but div is a block element and span is inline.

Comment: how are they used though?

Answer (score -1):

Div tends to be for a container that will house a few to many elements.  A span tag is a more suitable for a single string of text, traditionally.